# Saving canvas images around 300 in an array and sending it once to process it crashes in chrome but works fine in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-chrome, canvas

I have a JS file which runs the canvas animation. What I do is create a function to grab its contents by `toDataURL` and push that URL data to array.

At the end I send the ajax request to process that array and create images of it. 
When I do this on firefox it works fine , But when try to do it on chrome , the error message comes.

I think the problem is the post data i.e the array becomes too large that it crashes.

```
function encode_array() {
  var myjson = JSON.stringify(imgg);
  $.post('localhost:82/html5-video-maker/presentation/array_data1', {
    data: my‌json
  }); //
  return;
}

function makevideo() {
  if (anim) {
    if (flag_video == 1) {
      imgg[cnt] = cs.toDataURL();
    } else {
      imgg[cnt] = canvas.toDataURL();
    }
    cnt++;
  } else {
    encode_array(); //
    doRequest(0);
    clearInterval(t);
  }
}
var t = setInterval('makevideo()', 0.0003);
```

When can be the solution regarding this ?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Aww Snap!Some thing went wrong while displaying this webpage.To continue , reload or go to another page.

Comment: Post your code, please?

Comment: Where do I post my code. Its not allowing to paste it in the comment.

Comment: function encode_array(){
 var myjson = JSON.stringify(imgg);
  
     $.post('http://localhost:82/html5-video-maker/presentation/array_data1',{data:myjson});
     //return;
}
                            
function makevideo() {
 if(anim) {
  if(flag_video==1){
  imgg[cnt] = cs.toDataURL();
  } else {
  imgg[cnt] = canvas.toDataURL();
  }
  cnt++;
 } else {
                                encode_array();
  //doRequest(0);
  clearInterval(t);
 }
 }
 var t = setInterval('makevideo()', 0.0003); 
} These are the two functions which grabs the canvas data. and at the end it sends the post request

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your JS.

First: you should probably use `imgg.push(flag_video == 1 ? cs.toDataURL() : canvas.toDataURL())` as this may optimize better than your manual indexing.

Second: your data is probably freakishly huge.

Third: you are using a string for your setInterval instead of passing the function `setInterval(makevide)`

Fourth: and likely the source of your problem, is that you are using setInterval with a really small time interval... this is probably flooding, and overloading the stack;  The time to process toDataURL is probably more than your interval you are timing against.

You may be better off using `setImmediate` or `setTimeout(fn,0)`;

```
var nextms = new Date().getTime();
function makevideo(){
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  //no ms have passed
  if (now >= nextms) return setTimeout(makevideo,0);
  nextms = now + 16; //60fps ~= 16.666 ms

  //more than one frame of time has passed, get a frame
  imgg.push(flag_video == 1 ? cs.toDataURL() : canvas.toDataURL());

  //keep going until there are 300 frames of animation
  if (imgg.length < 300) return setTimeout(makevideo,0);

  encode_array();
  doRequest(0);
};
```

Now, odds are each iteration is more than 16ms, this should keep your frames at least 16ms apart.

As an aside, if you are doing requestanimationframe, then you should probably do this call after each animationframe completes instead of such a crude method.